# Call log in Android

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider, calllog

Is there any way by which one can get log call history(only duration of call) for a particular contact in android. Say there is "X" person in my contact list, I want to find out the duration of call we both talked( so both incoming and outgoing) in past days (it is user given, can be a day, a week, a month etc.) .

I got across this code while searching but I think this might just give the last talk details. Please correct if I am wrong.

```
    String[] strFields = {
         android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
         android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
         android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
         android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE
         };
    String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC"; 

    Cursor mCallCursor = getContentResolver().query(
         android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
         strFields, null, null,strOrder);
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Have a look on this link. Hope it will help you http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/androidcalllogdeletion/

Comment: Is there will be a problem if you leave the cursor open ?, I mean is that will be a problem for the android system keep manageing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be two approach,

1. put the right filter in Cursor.
2. Iterate the Cursor to collect the data.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. Could you tell me if this cursor contains only those call information which are being displayed in the actual call-log app in Android device. The reason why I ask this is that I have to know the details of call-duration from like past 1 week or so, but I do not think the call log thing contains this much  information. I think it just contains the last 20 calls details.

Comment: CallLog.Calls gives only the recent call log, does anybody knows if there is a way to get call log for calls made earlier (like in past month or week).

Comment: I don't think they store they can provide all the call log. If you really need then, you can do periodic backup. If above answer address your original question then mark as complete.

Comment: Hey Rajnikant, thanks for pointing out the backup thing. Can you tell me how can I get a listener to end of any call(both incoming and outgoing) ,which should also give me the contact number and the call duration.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED